Transfer Call from Twilio to Asterisk Without Duration Charges
I am trying to achieve the following use case:

A caller dials a Twilio number.

2.After some time or under certain conditions, Twilio forwards the
call to an  Asterisk server.

Asterisk receives the call from Twilio and immediately connects the caller to sip:test@sip.linphone.org (essentially bridging the caller directly to the SIP address).
Once the call is connected between the caller and sip:xxxx@sip.linphone.org, Twilio should no longer be involved in the call (to avoid duration charges).

The desired flow is:
Caller → Twilio → Asterisk → sip:test@sip.linphone.org
At the end, the connection should be:
Caller → sip:test@sip.linphone.org
I understand that I will need to pay Twilio for the incoming and outgoing leg until the caller is connected to Linphone SIP. However, I do not want Twilio to continue counting and charging for the whole call duration once the connection is established between the caller and the SIP address.
Problem:
Right now, the call flow works, and the Linphone client receives the call successfully. However, Twilio continues to log the call duration and charge for the entire duration of the call.
Here is my current configuration:
These are the complete configurations for receiving calls from Twilio and connecting the caller with Linphone SIP using Asterisk.
extensions.conf:
[from-twilio]

exten => s,1,NoOp(Call received from Twilio)

exten =>s,n,NoOp(Forwarding to sip:test@sip.linphone.org)

exten => s,n,Dial(PJSIP/sip-linphone)  ; Forward the call to Linphone
SIP    address

exten => s,n,NoOp(Call to sip-linphone ended)     exten =>
s,n,Hangup()


pjsip.conf:
[transport-udp-nat]

type=transport
protocol=udp
bind=0.0.0.0
local_net=xx.xx.xx.xx/16
external_media_address=xx.xx.xx.xx
external_signaling_address=xx.xx.xx.xx

[twilio0-aors]

type=aor
contact=sip:test.sip.twilio.com:5060

twilio-trunks

type=endpoint
transport=transport-udp-nat
context=from-twilio
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
direct_media=yes
force_rport=yes
rewrite_contact=yes

twilio0

aors=twilio0-aors

[twilio0-ident]

type=identify
endpoint=twilio0
match=54.172.60.0
match=54.172.60.1
match=54.172.60.2
match=54.172.60.3

[twilio0-auth]

password=xxxxxx
username=xxxxxx

[sip-linphone]

type=endpoint
transport=transport-udp-nat
context=from-sip-linphone
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
aors=sip-linphone-aors
direct_media=yes
force_rport=yes
rewrite_contact=yes

[sip-linphone-aors]

type=aor
contact=sip:xxxx@sip.linphone.org:5060

[linphone]

type=endpoint
context=from-pstn
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
aors=linphone
refer_blind_progress=yes

[linphone]

type=aor
contact=sip:linphone.org

[linphone]

type=auth
auth_type=userpass
password=xxxxx
username=xxxxx

Question:

How can I configure Asterisk (or Twilio) so that Twilio disconnects
completely after the call is bridged between the caller and
sip:xxxx@sip.linphone.org?
Is there a way to use Transfer or any other method to hand off the call to Asterisk   entirely and stop Twilio's billing?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!
